# If Exist statement is running when it should not -- MS SQL Server 2014 error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the below statement `Field1` does not exist. `IF EXIST` will return false and the select statement on line 3 should not run.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM  Database1.sys.columns 
           WHERE NAME = 'Field1' 
             AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('Database1.dbo.Table1')) 
    SELECT D.Field1 
    FROM Database1.dbo.Table1 D
```

However, when I run this, I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'Field1'.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I need to query the table if `Field1` exists.

Please note that database1 exists and field1 does not exist.

Comment: The stored proc is compiled to a plan before it's executed, so the compiler looks for a `Field1` field regardless of the run-time result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use dynamic SQL:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  Database1.sys.columns WHERE NAME = 'Field1' 
AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('Database1.dbo.Table1')) 
    EXEC('SELECT D.Field1 FROM Database1.dbo.Table1 D');
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Can you please explain why I need to use dynamic SQL with IF Exist? I would expect IF EXIST not run if something returns false.

Comment: @Lamak could you please explain why you need dynamic sql?

Comment: SQL is not running it... its checking that the objects exists before even trying to run a single line of code.  Dynamic SQL gives you a way to pass the pre-validation and let the script start to run.

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo I believe.

you had:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  Database1.sys.columns WHERE NAME = 'Field1' 
AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('Database1.dbo.Table1')) 
    SELECT D.Field1 
    FROM Database1.dbo.Field1 D
```

try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  sys.columns WHERE NAME = 'Field1' 
AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('Database1.dbo.Table1')) 
    SELECT D.Field1 
    FROM Database1.dbo.Table1 D
```

as I dont have the database and teh table this is my results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kamran. The typo was created when I modified the statement to hide the actual table names. I am still getting the error with the above fix.

Comment: @user7525429 did you try running the code. I noticed you had  Database1.sys.columns. you just need  sys.columns

Comment: No, this will throw an error if `Field1` doesn't exists

Comment: @Lamak are you sure? because the if clause will prevent that.

Comment: yup, it was the typo, sorry

Comment: I forgot to add this detail: Database1 exists and field1 does not exist. I think yours is working because database1 does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT D.Field1 
FROM Database1.dbo.Field1 D
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  sys.columns WHERE NAME = 'Field1' 
              AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('Database1.dbo.Table1'))
```

Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA: ([MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx))

```
SELECT D.<Field Name> 
FROM <Catalog>.<Schema>.<Table name> D
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
              WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = <Catalog>
                    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = <Schema>
                    AND TABLE_NAME = <Table name>
                    AND COLUMN_NAME = <Column name>)
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/LVB42621